# Categorize values in pandas dataframe based on previous value

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write a function that categorizes value in dataframe based on value from previous column. 
For example :
If previous value ='0' an current is <> 0 then it returns 'new', 
if previous value and current is the same  then 'Old' 
and if current value = 0 and previous was <>0 then'drop off'

Example

Input:

```
Date   1/1   1/2   1/3   1/4   1/5
a       0     0     0     1     2
b       1     2     3     4     5
c       1     0     2     3     0
```

Output:

```
 Date   1/1   1/2   1/3   1/4   1/5
a       NA    Old   Old   New   Old
b       NA    Old   Old   Old   Old
c       NA    Drop  New   Old   Drop
```

Comment: output is wrong

Comment: Which one do you think is wrong?

Comment: why 1/2,a is Old?

Comment: OK, you're right with the conditions I gave it shouldn't be 'old'. I editted the post.